# How to select all records that match with the concatenation of (name, surname) OR (surname, name)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using an ajax live search to select all users whose concatenation of name and surname match with the text entered, and it works fine:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE concat(name,' ',surname ) LIKE ?";
```

Now, I would like to match the same users also with the opposite concatenation that is surname - name. I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (concat(name,' ',surname ) LIKE ?) or (concat(surname,' ',name ) LIKE ?)";
```

```php
if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
  // Prepare a select statement
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (concat(name,' ',surname ) LIKE ?) or (concat(surname,' ',name ) LIKE ?)";

  if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

    // Set parameters
    $param_term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

      // Check number of rows in the result set
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        // Fetch result rows as an associative array
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
          echo "<p>" . $row["name"] . " " . $row["surname"] .  "</p>" 
        }
      } else{
        echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
      }
    } else{
      echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
  }

  // Close statement
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

I expext to match the same users but I receive the message:

> **ERROR:** Could not able to execute SELECT * FROM users WHERE
>   (concat(name,' ',surname ) LIKE ?) or (concat(name,' ',surname ) LIKE
>   ?).

Comment: `mysqli_error` needs the `$conn`, not `$link`. Use that and provides us with the actual error message please.

Comment: Do you use $link or $conn to for your connection? Can you show your connection line?

Comment: Sorry, I use $conn for my connection. Anyway, when I change it, mysqli_error($conn) shows any error because the connection is ok. I change that line with mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) and the error output is No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement. Jan found the solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got two placeholders `?` in your query-string but only binding one variable to the statement. Try to bind it a second time, so the count matches.

```php
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_term, $param_term);
```